# Cookie does not store any section ID after the google authentication is successful in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, express-session

I use Node.js and Express.js with passport-google-oauth20 and express-session to allow users to login with their google accounts. Everything works well on my local host until I deploy my vite full-stack application on Vercel. I think that there is a trouble with express-session middleware that make the section ID not created and the deserializeUser is not run too. Below is my code in the Index.js. Please help me to figure out why there is no section ID returned after the user is authenticated with their google accounts.

```
//SET UP CORS MIDDLEWARE
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

//MIDDLEWARE TO PARSE DATA IN REQUEST BODY AND MAKE IT AVAILABLE IN REQ.BODY
app.use(express.json());

//APPLY HELMET TO ADD SOME HTTP HEADERS FOR SECURITY ENHANCEMENT
app.use(helmet());

//APPLY COOKIE PARSER TO PARSE DATA STORED IN COOKIE AND MAKE IT AVAILABLE IN REQ.COOKIES
app.use(cookieparser());

//SET UP THE EXPRESS SESSION MIDDLEWARE
app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);

//INITIALIZE PASSPORT
app.use(passport.initialize());

// PASSPORT SESSION CALL THE DESERIALIZEUSER FUNCTION AND PASS THE USER ID TO THE PARAMETER OF THIS FUNCTION
app.use(passport.session());

//IMPLEMENT GOOGLE STRATEGY
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `https://nasa-app-backend.vercel.app/auth/google/callback`,
    },
    function (_accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) {
      const { id: google_id, name: nameObj } = profile;

      //CHECK TO SEE IF THIS USER IS IN DATABASE
      User.findOne({ google_id: google_id, username: nameObj.givenName })
        .then((user) => {
          //IF THIS USER EXISTS IN DATABASE
          if (user) {
            done(null, { _id: user._id });
          }

          //IF THIS IS A NEW USER
          else {
            User.create({ google_id: google_id, username: nameObj.givenName })
              .then((res) => {
                done(null, { _id: res._id });
              })
              .catch((e) => console.log(`Error creating a user ${e}`));
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(`Error fetching a user ${e}`));
    }
  )
);

//SET UP SERIALIZEUSER
passport.serializeUser((userObj, done) => {
  console.log(userObj);
  done(null, userObj._id);
});

//SSET UP DESERIALIZEUSER
passport.deserializeUser((userId, done) => {
  console.log(userId);
  User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    .then((user) => done(null, { _id: user._id, username: user.username }))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("Error finding user");
    });
});

//CONNECT TO THE MONGODB DATABASE
handleConnectMongoDBServer();

//APPLY ROUTES
app.use("/auth", googleAuthRoute); //Put the /auth first to ensure that req.user is set before the JWT check token middlewares are invoked
app.use("/user-profile", userProfileRoute);
app.use("/login", loginRoute);
app.use("/signup", signupRoute);
app.use("/logout", logoutRoute);

//START THE SERVER
app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Website is listening to the port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```